# Does Queueable Apex job run if parent process crashes?

Tags: email2case, queueable-apex

We are using a custom Email To Case Handler apex class.  So that we can keep track of incoming emails if the custom handler crashes for any reason, we have just implemented code at the start of the handler to call a Queueable Apex class, and pass it the incoming email and envelope.  What we are finding is that if the custom email handler crashes, then Queueable job does not seem to run.  If the custom email handler finishes without crashing, then and only then does the Queuable job run.  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. A transaction must run to completion (complete without hitting a governor limit, failed assertion, or uncaught exception), or the entire transaction will be rolled back, including any emails sent with Messaging.sendEmail, jobs queued with System.enqueueJob, System.schedule, or Database.executeBatch, and so on. While you're here reading this answer, be sure to [vote on this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5BvAAI).

Comment: Thanks Fox.  Do you have a link to where this is "officially" documented?

Comment: I think platform events are exception for this right? Platform events are fired even if the parent transaction fails.

Comment: @hamayoun It's kind of described in a round-about way in a few places, like ["Any DML operations that were processed before the exception are rolled back and aren’t committed to the database."](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_definition.htm) and ["If the request does not complete successfully, all database changes are rolled back."](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm). Nowhere does say that emails and jobs are also rolled back, but implied.

Comment: @javanoob Yes, mentioned as [The event insertion occurs non-transactionally. As a result, you can’t roll back published events.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_apex.htm).